# Limit Query in publication

Tags: meteor, publish-subscribe, meteor-blaze

Hello I'm trying to implement my own pagination, but I'm getting the following error when trying to limit the publication query.

> Exception from sub Products id Xbd4EW32oob8fBPkk Error: must use
>   ordered observe (ie, 'addedBefore' instead of 'added') with skip or
>   limit

```
Meteor.publish('Products', function(user, options) {
            if (organization && organization.categories) {
                //find products in array of categories
                let products = Products.find({
                                categories: {
                                        '$in': organization.categories
                                }                    
                            },
                            {limit: 10}
                            );
                return products;
            } else {
                return [];
            }
        });
```

Subscription  Code:

```
Router.route('/products', {
    name: 'products',
    loadingTemplate: 'loading',

    waitOn: function() {
        // return one handle, a function, or an array
        return Meteor.subscribe('Products', {limit: 10});
    },

    data: function () {
        return Products.find({});
    },

    action: function() {
        this.render('ProductCatalog');
    }

});
```

Full error trace:

```
I20170320-16:29:58.231(0)? Exception from sub Products id vDz4GLRXJ6s3cENeE Error: must use ordered observe (ie, 'addedBefore' instead of 'added') with skip or limit
I20170320-16:29:58.233(0)?     at [object Object]._.extend.observeChanges (packages/minimongo/minimongo.js:325:13)
I20170320-16:29:58.234(0)?     at [object Object].<anonymous> (packages/omknee:sales-process/sales-process.js:38:31)
I20170320-16:29:58.235(0)?     at [object Object]._handler (packages/omknee:access-control/access-control.js:38:31)
I20170320-16:29:58.236(0)?     at maybeAuditArgumentChecks (packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:1737:12)
I20170320-16:29:58.236(0)?     at [object Object]._.extend._runHandler (packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:1035:17)
I20170320-16:29:58.237(0)?     at [object Object]._.extend._startSubscription (packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:853:9)
I20170320-16:29:58.238(0)?     at [object Object]._.extend.protocol_handlers.sub (packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:625:12)
I20170320-16:29:58.239(0)?     at packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:559:43
I20170320-16:29:58.246(0)? Auth Strategy - Local. User : {"user":{"email":"laetitia.mendes@omknee.com"},"password":{"digest":"5e884898da28047151d0e56f8dc6292773603d0d6aabbdd62a11ef721d1542d8","algorithm":"sha-256"}}
```

Comment: It looks like you are going an `observe` on a cursor somewhere.  Can you post that code as well?

Comment: @jordanwillis I'm not using observe anywhere in my app

Comment: What version of meteor are you using?

Comment: 1.4.3.2 @jordanwillis

Comment: the combination of $elemMatch and $in looks weird to me. can you try it with just the $in?

Comment: Yes, the $elemMatch wasn't doing anything there. I removed it. The problem remains, still

Comment: Can you share your subscription code?

Comment: @jordanwillis added

Comment: @jordanwillis the work around I'm using is publishing the whole collection and limiting afterwards

Comment: Can you post this code: `packages/omknee:sales-process/sales-process.js`.  You mentioned you are not using observe anywhere in your app, but what about this package?

Comment: @jordanwillis  
that's the "Meteor.publish" code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there anyway you can add `sort` to your find options (typically `limit` is used alongside `sort`).  Here is why I make this recommendation.

When you publish a cursor, Meteor will then automatically setup an `observe` on that query so that changes can be sent down to the subscriber.  However, when the query is sorted, meteor will automatically setup an `observeChanges` instead.  I think this difference is what is causing the error.  Meteor used 'observe' instead of 'observeChanges'.

I see that some issues have been logged to meteor about this situation (e.g. [#2766](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/2766) and [#1643](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/1643)) but I don't see that any resolution was put into place.

Another reason why you will want to add a `sort` option is because [Meteor won't be able to use the oplog for this query](https://kadira.io/academy/meteor-performance-101/content/optimize-your-app-for-oplog).

> If your query has a limit but not a sort specifier, your query can't take advantage of oplog

With all that said, I can't pinpoint **exactly** why you are getting the error, but given the above, I'm guessing this is what is happening.

Comment: I'm getting the same error with the following options { sort: { name: 1 }, limit: 10 }

Comment: hmm...let me try some stuff locally to see if I can figure this out then.

Comment: @MMrj can you post the code for `packages/omknee:sales-process/sales-process.js`?

Comment: I'm stumped.  I tested this (adding a `limit` option to a query in a publication) both directly in my app as well as from within a package that it used by my app (which is what it seems you are doing?) and it worked without issue.  The only variable that is different between your project and mine is that I'm not using IronRouter and I am subscribing to the publication directly in my Template.  Maybe IronRouter is trying to observe your subscription as an intermediary and causing the problem?  Try moving your subscription directly into your template and see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: thanks for all the help, I found a workaround that should solve dthe problem. I also created an issue at meteor github, so that they can further analyse this problem